# Create multidimensional arrays ( n-dimensions )

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3

I have a string : a - b - c and I would like to create a array.

A [] >> B [] >> C []

```
var f:Array = "a-b-d".split('-');
var tree:Array = new Array;
for (var i:Number=0; i < f.length ;  i++)
{
   var o:Object = new Object
  o.name = f[i];
  o.path = f.slice(0,i);
 o.isDirectory = (i == f.length)? false :true ;
}
```

I would like this

```
var x:Array = new Array(new Array(new Array()));
```

Is this the right way? Or how could I do?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can create a multi-dimensional array within arrays. It might be useful to create an "Object" instead, and have Array as collections for those objects, given your data model. And it may be useful to create helper methods to search, retrieve, update, and delete items within that structure.

The problem is how is your string structured? Is it only 3 levels deep? This is untested code, and based on assumptions you've laid out that your string structure is only a set level deep.

Here's how, using your code:

```
var f:Array = "a-b-c".split('-');

// create first dimension of arrays (tree)
var tree:Array = new Array();
var secondTree:Array = new Array();
var thirdTree:Array = new Array();

secondTree.push(thirdTree);
tree.push(secondTree);

// create second dimension of arrays (tree)
for (var i:int=0; i < f.length;  i++)
{
   var o:Object = new Object
   o.name = f[i];
   o.path = f.slice(0,i);
   o.isDirectory = (i == f.length)? false : true;

   if(i%3 == 0) {
     thirdTree.push(o);
   } else if(i%2 == 0) {
     secondTree.push(o);
   } else {
     tree.push(o);
   }
}
```